# How do I convert array type?

Tags: swift

How do I convert defined `let a = [1, 2, 3]` to `Array<CustomStringConvertible>` most convenient?

Something like `a as! [CustomStringConvertible]`, `let b: [CustomStringConvertible] = a`, `let b = Array<CustomStringConvertible>(s: a)`...

Comment: What is your use case?  Converting an array of numbers into an array of Strings?

Comment: Rather general array type conversion.

Comment: So far `let b = a.map({ $0 as CustomStringConvertible })` is best I've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

`let a = [1, 2, 3]` is already an array of types conforming to `CustomStringConvertible`, since `a` is an `[Int]`, and `Int` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` through an extension:

```
extension Int : CustomStringConvertible {
    /// A textual representation of `self`.
    public var description: String { get }
}
```

So this will always work:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3] as? Array<CustomStringConvertible> // Conditional cast always succeeds
```

Comment: Yes it is! And this is why I wonder why I can't retype it somehow convenient. So I can do `b.append(NSObject())` for example.

Comment: `let b = a as? Array<CustomStringConvertible>` doesn't work in playground

Comment: @MaximKosov Yes because a is an optional that needs to be unwrapped.  `if let a = [1, 2, 3] as? Array<CustomStringConvertible> { let b = a as? Array<CustomStringConvertible> }` works

Comment: @JAL try to create array of ints: `let a = [1, 2, 3]` and then cast it like so: `let b = a as? [CustomStringConvertible]`. Playground shows an error. Not the optional.

Comment: @MaximKosov oh I see what you're saying, working on a solution now

Comment: Yes, `a` is already inferred while with `[1, 2, 3] as [CustomStringConvertible]` you get explicit.

Comment: Yep.  I'm trying with `unsafeBitCast` and `unsafeDowncast` now but I don't think those work with collections of Swift value types.

Comment: @StanislavSmida I think you `map` solution is the best answer.

Comment: Yep, looks like. Anyway, I'll keep this open for some time. Thanks for your effort. Both of you. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A good question!

As I thought, Swift supports covariance for `Array` type, but it seems that covariance is supported only for classes. For example, this piece of code

```
class Animal {

}

class Cat: Animal {

}

let cats = [Cat(), Cat()]
let animals: [Animal] = cats
```

works perfectly. But if we change `class Animal` to `protocol Animal` it stops working and shows the error.

So, I think the solution is

- If both types are classes then use covariance `let animals: [Animal] = cats`
- If you need to cast array to array of protocols use `let b = a.map { $0 as CustomStringConvertible }`